# BigQuery/ SQL cumulative sum with group by date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio, cumulative-sum

I have a score which I classify as bad, normal or good.
So I wrote a Query which shows me each class count grouped by the day.

```js
date        bad   normal    good
01.10       2     4         2
02.10       null  4         3
03.10       1     null      5
04.10       3     1         1
05.10       5     1         null
```

But I need the cumulative sum up to each date.
Like this

```js
date        bad   normal    good
01.10       2     4         2
02.10       2     8         5
03.10       3     8         10
04.10       6     9         11
05.10       11    10        11
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select date, 
  sum(sum(bad)) over win as bad,
  sum(sum(normal)) over win as normal,
  sum(sum(good)) over win as good
from your_table
group by date
window win as (order by date)
```

if applied to your case - output is

[image]